# Using scanner to produce arrays

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am using java and want to use a Scanner to get user input and then output arrays.

I've created a file that works for one and a separate file for the other, but I want to ask the user questions and get custom array properties back (variable number of arrays, variable rows, variable columns, variable addition, subtraction, and multiplication of the array)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ScannerDemoforNetbeans
{

public static void main (String [] args)throws IOException
{
//`enter code here`
System.out.println ("Okay, you got it! How many rows  do you want");
   Scanner rc= new Scanner (System.in);
   public static rows;
   rows= rc.nextInt();
   System.out.println ("How many columns do you want?");
   Scanner c = new Scanner (System.in);
   public static columns;
   columns = c.nextInt();
   System.out.println ("Rows" + rows);
   System.out.println ("Columns:" + columns);


}
   // }   
   // public static void createarray (String [] args)
   // {
    int matWidth = ScannerDemoforNetbeans.columns;
        int matHeight = ScannerDemoforNetbeans.rows;
        int maxCellValue = 70;

                    int [][] mat1 = new int [matHeight][matWidth];
                    int [][] mat2 = new int [matHeight][matWidth];
                    int [][] sum = new int [matHeight][matWidth];

                    for (int i=0; i<matHeight; ++i)
                    {
                        for (int j=0; j<matWidth; ++j)
                        {
                            java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
                            mat1 [i][j]= r.nextInt (maxCellValue);
                            mat2 [i][j] = r.nextInt (maxCellValue);
                        }
                    }

                    print2Darray (mat1);
                    System.out.println ();
                    print2Darray (mat2);
                    for (int i=0; i<matHeight; ++i)
                    {
                        for (int j=0; j<matWidth; ++j)
                        {
                            sum [i][j]= mat1 [i][j] + mat2 [i][j];
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println ();
                    print2Darray (sum);
    }
    public static void print2Darray (int[][]arr)
    {
        for (int [] i : arr)

        {
          for (int j : i)  
          {
              System.out.print (j + " ");
          }
        System.out.println();
        }
    System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to try yourself, then show us the source code if it doesn't work *then* ask. We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: System.out.println ("Okay, you got it! How many rows  do you want");
   Scanner rc= new Scanner (System.in);
   public static rows;
   rows= rc.nextInt();
   System.out.println ("How many columns do you want?");
   Scanner c = new Scanner (System.in);
   public static columns;
   columns = c.nextInt();
   System.out.println ("Rows" + rows);
   System.out.println ("Columns:" + columns);

Comment: hold on im trying to get my code up here

Comment: You should edit it into the main question instead.

Comment: @TyArmour Do you have main method in your code? I don't see it in posted code.

Comment: yea ill edit it in for you.

Comment: im still getting up and running so be patient with me

Comment: i also have my imports before my class so im good on that note too.

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you have encountered with what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Code-Guru He has lot of problems. I tried to put his code and got tons of errors. `public static rows;` and `public static columns;` This is just start.

Comment: rows and colums. They work seperately.

Comment: that was the hole thing. The two programs when compiled seperately run, but when I try to write them together it fails.

Comment: its only when i try to make columns and rows a variable that the program wont compile

Comment: I don't think you will be able to compile this code. It will throw error on `public static rows;` and `public static columns;`. They should be `public static int rows;` and `public static int columns;`

Comment: if i keep columns and rows as an integer, then it compiles fine and runs fine

Comment: Yes you need to declare their type. You really need to read some beginner java tutorials.

Comment: okay, ill start over again. I really want to do this and complete this program. I basically want to store the integers as variables, then use the variables to create matricies

Comment: how could I store the integer return values as variables, and how exactly would i access them in a sub method?

Comment: FIrst go through this and try to grasp the concepts. Then try this program [Tutorial Link 1](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/) and [Tutorial link 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: alright ill go through this. For sure. then ill try again. ITs just when I try to combine things together. I can get through each program, but havent figured out how to combine things. like I just need help with the combination of the two programs. like how to use a scanner to generate an array

Comment: Ill get more information and stuff. I dont have a 20 reputation so i cant go. but nbd. Ill search more and more for storing and acessing variables and loops and stuff. Ill get this up and running sooner or later

Comment: Thank you all for the help and the point in the right direction. it is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
package araay;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Araay {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

      Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
     int i=0;
     int j=0;
     int arr[][]=new int [3][3];
     System.out.println ("Enter the numbers");

     for (i=0;i<=3;i++)
          for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
     arr[i][j]=a.nextInt();>>>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at araay.Araay.main(Araay.java:18)//this error is occur in this code plz solve it



     for (i=0;i<=3;i++)
     for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
      System.out.println("The matrix of array is "+arr[i][j]+"\t");
      System.out.println();
    }


}
```